# url rewirting in operncart search page is not working

Tags: url, url-rewriting, opencart

`I want my search url should be like this mydomain.in/compare/samsung%20galaxy` and my `htaccess` is like this

```
RewriteRule ^compare\/(.*)$ index.php?route=product/search&search=$1
```

However, it is not working, this is going to page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash at the start before compare:

```
RewriteRule ^/compare\/(.*)$ index.php?route=product/search&search=$1
```

Comment: no it is not working, the url given in the question is working fine while checking in this tool http://htaccess.mwl.be/. But the same is not working in the server.

Comment: I just tried both your original and my suggestion in that test site and neither worked for me, so it may be something else in your fill htaccess causing the issue?